# Is it okay to ask for a week off between an internship and part-time work?

Tags: internship, united-states, time-off

I'm a software engineering intern and so far I've completed 12 of 13 weeks of my internship. So far I've only missed one day due to car trouble. Recently my internship was extended part time until the end of the year.

I had planned to have the week before school begins off for vacation. Also, I'd like to have the first week of school off to dedicate some time to starting a research project I am doing.

Should this be okay to ask for?

Comment: Seams pretty reasonable.

Comment: Unless you have a tyrant as a boss, I see no problem

Comment: Is it a paid or unpaid internship?

Comment: What does your contract say?

Comment: I made an edit to clarify this question. I believe the circumstances here are different from the duplicate question @Chad linked, which focuses more on a few days known about prior to even joining the company.

Comment: @enderland If not duplicate then its really company specific.  I thought duplicate at least gives the OP some help with the answers there.  Not to mention your answer here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just ask your boss and tell him what you said here. Assuming "end of the year" means December 2016, there will almost assuredly be no problems.

Unless you have a critical deadline, there's pretty much no reason for your boss to say no. Given you are an intern going to parttime, the likelihood here is pretty low.

I will add in the future it's best to give more notice on something like this.

Comment: As much notice as possible is almost always better. However, in this case, longer notice may not have been reasonable. The OP stated "recently my internship was extended". This may indicate the previously scheduled end date was prior to the when the OP desires to not be working. Thus, there was no reason for the OP to discuss a desire not to be working during a time after the internship was scheduled to be terminated. The first point it would have been known there was a conflict was upon notification to the OP that the internship was extended (earlier if the extension was at the OP's request).

Comment: @Makyen in that conversation: "I'd love to work parttime through the school year! However, I was planning on taking some time off before school - I assume this would be ok to take a week off?" or something like that.